# How to automatically open a windows form inside an instantiated COM object?

Tags: c#, com

Good day. I have this task where in i need to create a windows debugger form that will accept request from a javascript file run by a uiagent. It is going to be implemented using COM object. I already created a COM object using c# and successfully registered it. I also successfully instantiated that COM object in the java script file and cal already execute a function from my COM object. My problem is, from my COM object, how can i instantiate a windows form and open that form automatically when my COM object gets instantiated?

What I have tried:

namespace is RouterInterface

form name is DebuggerforMexUI

```
[Guid("xxxxxxx")]
public interface IConnection
{
    void SendToDebugger(string rawData);
}

[ComVisible(true)]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
[ProgId("xxxxxx")]
[Guid("xxxxxx")]
public class XConnection : IConnection
{
    static XConnection instance;

    public static XConnection Singleton
    {
        get { return instance; }
    }

    public XConnection()
    {
    #if STRICT_INSTANCE
        if (instance != null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("AppRouter should be singleton");
        }
    #endif
        instance = this;

        try
        {
            DebuggerforMexUI dbgr = new DebuggerforMexUI();  **// This will    generate an error. "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."**
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }

public void SendToDebugger(string rawData)
{

}
```

Comment: Already found the solution. I just made a new form under the same COM project. Because before, the form that i tried to instantiate was just a copy from another project. Thank you.